# Backberry message view, chat view design

Tags: blackberry, chat, message

I want to design a chat view like [BlackBerry messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edCZg.jpg) (unfortunately new users are not allowed to post images).

The message header should include the sender's name, date, and seperator field.
Anyone can help on this ?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIM released some [sample code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276) to build Advanced UI interfaces. There you can find a Negative Margins example that simulates a Screen for Blackberry Messenger.

Comment: thanks for your help ! i've already try Advance UI interfaces, but i got stuck at adding a seperator field

Comment: oh, i found out that i can customize NegativeMarginVerticalFieldManager to add new field